# Требуется ли частица "ни"?

Tags: частица

Необходимо ли в следующем предложении ставить частицу "ни"?

> Я обучаюсь независимо не/ни от чего.

Answer (score 2):

Да, так как "ни" здесь усиливает отрицание "независимо".
[Примеры в корпусе русского](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE).

Answer (score 1):

Выбор НЕ/НИ в данном случае определяется **двумя способами**:

1)  **По значению**

При наличии слова с НЕ частица НИ усиливает отрицательное значение: ***От чего*** это зависит? ― **Не** зависит **ни от чего**.

2) **По ударению** (формальное решение, которое обычно применяется при различении НЕ и НИ)

*Не зависит **ни от чегО**. Здесь зависеть **нЕ от кого и  нЕ от чего.***

Аналогично: *ничегО ― нЕчего.* (Предлог же разбивает это местоимение на три слова).

[Примеры из Нацкорпуса](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&startyear=1982&text=lexform&req=%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE&endyear=2002&mode=main&env=alpha&nodia=1&p=2)

Comment: А следует ли писать раздельно с "не" слово "независимо"?

Comment: В вашем примере слитное написание наречия  "независимо". В Нацкорпусе  можно встретить раздельное написание НЕ, но частотность таких вариантов мала (33:8000).  Вероятно, при раздельном написании можно сослаться на правило,  когда НЕ пишется раздельно, если отрицает  словосочетание, а не слово.  А в данном  случае  обычно говорится именно о словосочетании -  "независимо от чего-либо.